# How does Kernel.get_in work with function as a key?

Tags: elixir

I am unable to figure out how this works. Here are example codes from Elixir docs, and my thought processes on how they work. Please let me know if there's something wrong.

```
# Code example from Elixir docs
users = [%{name: "john", age: 27}, %{name: "meg", age: 23}]
all = fn(:get, data, next) do
    Enum.map(data, next) 
end
get_in(users, [all, :age])
#=> [27, 23]
```

1. `users` is matched to a list that contains two maps.
2. `all` is matched to a function that takes `:get, data, next` as parameters and performs `Enum.map(data, next)`.
3. `Kernal.get_in(users, [all, :age])` is called.
4. Since one of the keys, `all`, is a function, it's invoked as `all(:get, users, next)`.
5. `Enum.map` iterates over each element of `users` and calls `next` on it, returning a list.
6. Value of `:age` key of each user in the list is returned as a list.

These are my questions based on this analysis:

1. What is this function `next`? It was never defined nor provided, but how come no error is reported?
2. Is it correct to summarize that when `get_in` is called with a function (in this example, `all`) as a key, it returns the values of keys  (in this example, `:age`) from the result of that function?
3. If my guess in 2. is correct, then what happens when the result of that function is not a dictionary type and does not have key-value pairs? Does it raise error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two perfect sources to retrieve info from. The first is Elixir Docs, that state for [`Kernel#get_in/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2):

> Gets a value from a nested structure.
>
> [...]
>
> If a key is a function, the function will be invoked passing three arguments, the operation (`:get`), the data to be accessed, and a function to be invoked next.

The ultimate source would be Elixir source code, where we can see the exact implementation of [`Kernel#get_in/2` in our particular case](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1747).

That said, `next` here plays the role of `acc`, to pass `get_in` forth to the tail recursion until list’s tail is empty.

The question 2 is perfectly answered in the docs.

The answer to the question 3 would be: [another `Kernel#get_in/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1745) will be matched on the previous step and the recursion will start to unveil.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe that the idea of looking at source code didn't come to my mind. It all makes sense now. I think what tripped me is that there's no explicit mention about recursive call to `get_in` in the docs. Maybe that's clear to those who're more familiar with FP, but it didn't dawn on me until I looked at the source code.

Comment: Welcome. Elixir source code itself is very clean, what makes it relatively easy to understand what’s happening under the hood in most cases. FYI: to access the source code directly from docs, one might simply press the `</>` link in the right top corner of respective function description.

Comment: The link to the source code is no good anymore.  Here is the correct link: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2249